# be64enc and other dec/enc equivalent functions from FreeBSD in Linux?

Tags: c, endianness

Do exist functions *dec/*enc (e.g. be64enc) in C library in Linux ? They do exist in FreeBSD but in Linux only I can find are hto*/*toh functions which have not exactly the same functionality I am afraid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just install `libbsd` on Linux and use whatever BSD functions you want. `libbsd` is basically the standard library for doing so.

Answer (score -1):

They do not:

```
$ uname
Linux
$ man be64enc
No manual entry for be64enc
```

A quick Google search confirms this, there are no Linux entries.

I couldn't find what those functions are supposed to do. This is the only manual page (BSD) on this subject and it isn't particularly helpful:

```
BYTEORDER(9)              BSD Kernel Developer's Manual              BYTEORDER(9)

NAME
     bswap16, bswap32, bswap64, be16toh, be32toh, be64toh, htobe16, htobe32, htobe64, htole16,
     htole32, htole64, le16toh, le32toh, le64toh, be16enc, be16dec, be32enc, be32dec, be64enc,
     be64dec, le16enc, le16dec, le32enc, le32dec, le64enc, le64dec -- byte order operations

SYNOPSIS
     #include <sys/endian.h>

     uint16_t
     bswap16(uint16_t int16);

     uint32_t
     bswap32(uint32_t int32);

     uint64_t
     bswap64(uint64_t int64);

     uint16_t
     be16toh(uint16_t big16);

     uint32_t
     be32toh(uint32_t big32);

     uint64_t
     be64toh(uint64_t big64);

     uint16_t
     htobe16(uint16_t host16);

     uint32_t
     htobe32(uint32_t host32);

     uint64_t
     htobe64(uint64_t host64);

     uint16_t
     htole16(uint16_t host16);

     uint32_t
     htole32(uint32_t host32);

     uint64_t
     htole64(uint64_t host64);

     uint16_t
     le16toh(uint16_t little16);

     uint32_t
     le32toh(uint32_t little32);

     uint64_t
     le64toh(uint64_t little64);

     uint16_t
     be16dec(const void *);

     uint32_t
     be32dec(const void *);

     uint64_t
     be64dec(const void *);

     uint16_t
     le16dec(const void *);

     uint32_t
     le32dec(const void *);

     uint64_t
     le64dec(const void *);

     void
     be16enc(void *, uint16_t);

     void
     be32enc(void *, uint32_t);

     void
     be64enc(void *, uint64_t);

     void
     le16enc(void *, uint16_t);

     void
     le32enc(void *, uint32_t);

     void
     le64enc(void *, uint64_t);

DESCRIPTION
     The bswap16(), bswap32(), and bswap64() functions return a byte order swapped integer.  On
     big endian systems, the number is converted to little endian byte order.  On little endian
     systems, the number is converted to big endian byte order.

     The be16toh(), be32toh(), and be64toh() functions return a big endian byte ordered integer
     converted to the system's native byte order.  The return value will be the same as the argu-
     ment on big endian systems.

     The le16toh(), le32toh(), and le64toh() functions return a little endian byte ordered inte-
     ger converted to the system's native byte order.  The return value will be the same as the
     argument on little endian systems.

     The htobe16(), htobe32(), and htobe64() functions return a integer in the system's native
     byte order converted to big endian byte order.  The return value will be the same as the
     argument on big endian systems.

     The htole16(), htole32(), and htole64() functions return a integer in the system's native
     byte order converted to little endian byte order.  The return value will be the same as the
     argument on little endian systems.

     The be16enc(), be16dec(), be32enc(), be32dec(), be64enc(), be64dec(), le16enc(), le16dec(),
     le32enc(), le32dec(), le64enc(), and le64dec() functions encode and decode integers to/from
     byte strings on any alignment in big/little endian format.

SEE ALSO
     byteorder(3)

HISTORY
     The hto*() and toh*() functions first appeared in FreeBSD 5.0, and were originally developed
     by the NetBSD project.

     The encode/decode functions first appeared in FreeBSD 5.1.

BSD                   April 29, 2002                      BSD
```

---

Perhaps we could better help you if you specified the problem you are facing and what you have tried. Ask a new question with details of your problem, what you have tried, and what may have worked on previous occasions for you.